# Git: как можно универсально накатить мастер ветку из удаленного репощитория, независимо от текущего состояния?

Tags: git

Мне необходимо автоматизировать деплой на дев-среду из гитхаба.
Если просто писать git pull origin master  - то могут быть конфликты и т.д.

Есть ли способ, принудительно накатывать мастер ветку, чтобы все локальные работы затирались.
т.е. чтобы после этой команды git status показывал пустоту?)

Comment: `git stash` + `git pull` ?

Comment: удалить папку, сделать clone

Answer (score 1):

```
git fetch
git reset --hard remotes/origin/master
```

Сначала выкачать изменения с сервера, затем принудительно сбросить текущую ветку на последний коммит из origin/master и переписать рабочую копию содержимым этого коммита.

Comment: но если локально будут какие-то новые файлы, незакомиченные, то они останутся.

Comment: Если это проблема, то можно добавить еще и `git clean`